# Screen flickering

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I have an MSI GS60 with an intel broadwell i7-5700HQ CPU and hybrid graphics (nvidia GTX ‎970‎M). The screen flickers so badly as shown in this video (seconds 0:03 and 0:08):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqAljJ0U5Pc

I know this is not a hardware problem since the issue doesn't happen on Windows 10 at all. I've tried many kernels and many distros and many drivers with no avail. I'm using the nvidia-352 driver with bumblebee right now. I'm not even sure if it's a graphics issue or a power issue or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Specs:

```
~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge - DMI (rev 0a)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 0a)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 0a)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 0a)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

-

```
~$ uname -a
Linux msi 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

-

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:a1000000-a1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is gone with Linux 4.6

Answer (score 0):

You have a very new GPU, so install and use the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers 361.

Replace `bumblebee` with `nvidia-prime` to switch between the two graphics solutions.

Uninstall every currently installed NVIDIA software and remove the `bumblebee` as well.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* '^bumblebee.*'  
sudo reboot
```

When the GRUB menu appears - select the Ubuntu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the Linux line, then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Note : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last sign in this line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Login and now install the NVIDIA drivers from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is still there, but it seems less severe. I tried the  `nvidia-361` and the `nvidia-364` and it still persists.
When I connect an external monitor via HDMI, the flickering doesn’t happen on the external monitor.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter to add a new line to my reply and it posted my comment too early :)
I've edited my comment but I'm not sure you get notified of edits.

Comment: Unfortunately my BIOS doesn't have the ability to switch between the two cards :(

Comment: If it didn't work fine on Windows 10, I would say for sure this is a hardware issue. I'll go and dig in the BIOS again just to make sure and I'll try to reinstall the drivers.